# Mono C# compiler interprets perfectly valid expression as an erroneous type argument

Tags: c#, syntax, compiler-errors

I was working on creating my own statically-typed language when I realized that it might not be possible to distinguish between an expression using the `<` operator and a type argument for a class or a method.

The main reason for this is that like C#, classes don't all have to be forward declared before they're used, so when an identifier is parsed following a `<`, it could either be an expression like `valueA < valueB` or it might be a type argument like `valueA<valueB>`.

So then I thought, maybe if there's a closing `>`, then it can be parsed as a type argument, but then I remembered that I wanted my language to have operator overloading, so expressions like `valueA < valueB > (valueC)` could be perfectly valid.

I decided to experiment with other languages, and I found that C# was the most similar to the language I was trying to create, and I may have broken it.

The expression `foo < bar > (2)` in the code below should be a perfectly valid expression because of the class with overloaded `<` and `>` operators.

To my knowledge, the expression should be parsed as `(foo < bar) > (2)`, but instead I get an error stating that `"The variable 'foo' cannot be used with type arguments."` To prove that this expression *should* be valid, I flipped the `<` and `>` signs so that the expression looked like `foo > bar < (2)`, and that program both compiled and printed out exactly what you'd expect, `MainClass+baz`.

In this particular example, the compiler could probably figure this out because it knows `foo` is a variable and it could assume that the `<` signifies an expression, but if foo was a static member of another class, there would be no way to distinguish between a `<` expression and a type argument.

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    baz foo = new baz();

    baz bar = new baz();

    // perfectly valid expression, results in error: The variable `foo' cannot be used with type arguments
    Console.WriteLine(foo < bar > (2));

  }

  class baz {
    public static baz operator<(baz l, baz r) {
      return l;
    }

    public static baz operator>(baz l, baz r) {
      return l;
    }

    public static baz operator<(baz l, int r) {
      return l;
    }

    public static baz operator>(baz l, int r) {
      return l;
    }

  }

  public String toString() {
    return "baz";
  }

}
```

My question is, how should this issue be dealt with in the C# compiler and with other languages?

I see a few options:

1. Report an error in ambiguous situations
2. Maybe there is some more context that can be used to resolve this ambiguity
3. C# is essentially broken and we should develop a new syntax for type arguments in future languages. If so, what should it look like?

Maybe there is some kind of standard on this, but I think that accepting this would just be negligence and we should at least go with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is a local variable but you try to use it as a class type name...

Therefore it is not a *perfectly valid expression* at all.

You can't write:

```
baz foo = new baz();
baz bar = new baz();

Console.WriteLine(foo<bar>(2));
```

But you can write:

```
var instance = baz<int>(2);
```

If you have:

```
class baz<T>
{
}
```

Here you try to create an instance of the class baz with generic type parameter int without using `new` keyword or perhaps it may be a cast miswritten, but the compiler can't know.

When you define the class `baz<T>` it is what is called an **open generic type**.

And when you instantiate `baz<int>` it is what is called a **closed constructed generic type**.

You write *the code below should be a perfectly valid expression because of the class with overloaded < and > operators*...

But the compiler can't interpret `val1 < val2 > (val3)` as `val1 < val2 && val2 > (val3)` as with the mathematical rule, or as `(val1 < val2) > (val3)` like you write you expect, because operator `<>()` has precedence over `<` and `>`.

The compiler think you try to use a `baz of T`, so the compiler outputs the error, because the compiler can't choose between the two cases, between `<>()` and `<` next `>`.

So the compiler interpret that as `Type<Type>(parameter)` and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think you completely understood my code or my question. I overloaded *both* the `<` and `>` operators to return baz objects rather than boolean values, so your analogy `2 > 1 < (3)` evaluates to `true > 3` does not apply here. The expression in my above code `foo > bar < (2)` would evaluate to `(baz obj) < (2)` which would then evaluate to just `(baz obj)`. I even said it compiles *because it does*, and since the reverse of `foo < bar > (2)` would have the same precedence order, it should also be a valid expression. Which of my 3 options should I go with?

Comment: You must write explicitaly: `(foo<bar)>(2)` or `foo < bar > 2` because operator `<>()` has precedence.

Comment: I am aware of that, but is it not a perfectly valid expression? The answer is yes unless the C# standard says something specifically about this issue. I know the difference between type arguments and `>` expressions, and if you read my question, you would see that I want to know if C# should report this as an error, and how I can avoid this issue in **my own language that I am designing**. I clearly described in detail that I knew what the problem was.

Comment: also, `<>()` does not have precedence, just `<>`, your second example won't compile, but your first one will. That was my bad for including the unnecessary `()` around the 2 in my question

Comment: Yes, `<>()` has precedence over `<` next `>`. This is a fact. Answer udpated.

Comment: Try and run my code with your second example `foo < bar > 2`. It won't compile, it will also read as a type argument and say `error CS1525: Unexpected symbol '2'`. `<>` and `<>()` both get read as a type argument list regardless of parentheses, so `<>` actually has precedence over the individual `<` and `>` operators. The ECMA standard does not describe this precedence and therefore this is an issue with the language implementation. My question is about language design, not about how to use C#. I do appreciate your answers though, it's mostly my bad for my phrasing of the question :)

Comment: `<>()` is not really an operator but a language structure. `<>` is the diamond operator. `foo < bar > 2` compiles with VS2017 and returns a baz instance. You got the error because of `<>()`.

Comment: I am using Mono C# compiler version 4.6.2.0, it must be an issue between implementations. My question still remains, how should this be dealt with in the C# ECMA standard and in other languages? should there be an error message for ambiguity? Should we use a different syntax altogether? This might just be a bad question on my part.

Comment: If Mono doesn't compile `foo < bar > 2`, there is a bug you can submit to the team: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues. But there is no bug with `foo<bar>(2)` that the compiler interpret as `Type<Type>(parameter)` and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but just out of curiosity, where does the standard say that? As far as I could tell it just said that a type argument list is between two `<` and `>` following an identifier. If the standard does specifically say something that indicates `foo<bar>2` should compile, I will gladly report it as a bug.

Comment: For C# 5.0: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029 or https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm. And this book for C# 4.0: https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Covering-Microsoft-Development-dp-0321741765/dp/0321741765

Comment: you just linked the standard, I already had it open in a tab. Where does it say that `foo<bar>2` should compile but `foo<bar>2` doesn't? What section? What paragraph?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't read it. p7-8 and p88-91 and p158 and after ? Perhaps you can ask to @EricLippert for example or direct submit the case to the Mono team.